# Loading test image into canvas

Tags: html, angularjs, unit-testing, canvas, karma-runner

I'm trying to test an AngularJS service that gets handed the ImageData from a canvas, does some pattern recognition, and returns the recognized patterns. I would like to write a *unit test* (not an E2E test), to build the service step by step. I fail to properly load a test-png image that I can draw onto a canvas, from which I then can extract the ImageData.

I would like to learn the proper way to solve my problem: Getting the ImageData object for a test-image in a unit test. What I am currently doing, using Karma, Jasmine 2, PhantomJS:

```
it('simple pattern', function (done) {
  var canvas = angular.element('<canvas></canvas>')
  var context = canvas[0].getContext("2d")

  var src = 'test/images/3x3-bw-1star.png'   // Not found by PhantomJS
  var src2 = "app/images/yeoman.png"         // Found.
  var image = angular.element('<img src="' + src + '"/>')
  image.onerror = function() {  // Not called.
    fail("Could not load image.")
    done()
  }
  image.onload = function() {  // Not called.
    context.drawImage(image[0], 0, 0)
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height)
    expect(starFinder.findStars(imageData)).toEqual(true)
    done()
  }
}
```

Problems with this code:

1. PhantomJS fails to load the test-image at src (404). The production image at src2 is correctly loaded. The path is correct, and I don't see any restriction to the "app" directory anywhere.
2. onload is never called. Probably, the event handler is attached to late, so when the angular.element call returns, the image is loaded already.
3. If I call onload manually, the context is undefined.

Comment: As first start, as you said I would attach the `onload` and `onerror` callbacks before attaching the `src` and report the error here.

Answer (score 0):

After @MarcoCI's (correct) suggestion, I thought I was seriously working on the wrong abstraction layer. Thus, I searched for a suitable image manipulation library, and stumbled upon [Caman](http://camanjs.com/). I then refactored the service to accept a caman object. In the test, I create a Caman object using a canvas and the image URL. Which feels correct for what I want to do: Get an image and have it analyzed.

The 404 error for the test images can be resolved by adding the image to the list of [files as served-but-not-included](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/files.html):

```
  {pattern: 'test/images/*.png', watched: true, served: true, included: false}
```

and then setting the urlRoot.

```
urlRoot: 'base'
```

The loading and event handling is done by Caman.